# can you recommend a workflow library or framework for a Java web app?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, workflow

I need to implement some workflow functionality; for example, user submits a document, it must be approved by a series of people before it is made publicly available.

I'm confident I could implement this from scratch, but are there existing Java based libraries or frameworks that can help do this sort of thing?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Activiti](http://www.activiti.org/). You can define your actual workflow process in either XML or you can use the Eclipse plugin that allows you to model your workflow graphically.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I started by looking at jBPM but it looks like Activiti is the better solution for me.

Answer (score 6):

There's no shortage of libraries for any purpose... It all comes down to your specific requirements.

Here you go: [Long Java Workflow Engines List](http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines)

Comment: Thanks, do you have any specific suggestions for doing something like I need to do?  (A simple series of a approvals on a document before making it public?)

Comment: @RobertHume - Bonita and jBPM have been around for a while and are pretty stable (or so I hear). jBPM is even integrated into JBoss' stack, for instance. As I said, it all depends on what you mean with approvals. Are they manual or automated? Does the tool need to have a UI or are you going to build it? Do you use BPMN or can you live with a system-dependent implementation? Check them out and take your pick (I imagine performance won't be an issue).

Comment: Manual approvals, users are emailed notifications of things they need to approve, then they log in to the web UI to approve.  I have to integrate with an existing web app so I was planning on building the UI myself, but if there's something existing that I can use then that's a bonus.  Re: BPMN, we're not using anything yet, so I'm open to any ideas.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RobertHume - Glad I could help. Beware that those are just a small number of things you should consider. The requirements can grow exponentially with time in these kind of platforms, so you should prepare for it (as soon your users realize what they can do, they'll always ask for more). Example: approvals tend to complicate themselves pretty quickly (think delegation, escalation, reconciliation, vacations/out of office, exception handling, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a system called [Documentum](http://www.emc.com/domains/documentum/index.htm) that does what you want.
It's not for a small project but large enterprise solutions.

Be advised though that it is expensive and very heavy weight.